# Running poclbm miner in Ubuntu 13.04 without ATI card

Tags: client, ubuntu, gpu-mining, poclbm

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit with 16GB RAM and this is my VGA card:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor     Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2200
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

When I try to run **poclbm** miner, it doesn't list any openCL devices and says *nothing to mine on* ?
Is there any other miner that I can use on Ubuntu to use and maximize the performance from my VGA card ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VGA card *has* no performance to maximise. Your CPU is more powerful for this kind of computation. I know, I have the same card.